# Python: Thread will not start

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a class inheriting from `threading.Thread`. For some reason the thread does not want to start.

Here is my code:

```
import time,threading,re,socket


class PyWatch(threading.Thread):

    filename = ""


    def __init__(self,filename):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print "initiating..."
        self.filename = filename


     def run(self):
        print "running..."
        thefile = open (self.filename)
        thefile.seek(0,2)      # Go to the end of the file
        while True:
                line = thefile.readline()
                if not line:
                     time.sleep(0.1)    # Sleep briefly
                     continue
                yield line
                self.process(line)


    def process(self,line):
        ip =  self.filterIPFromLine(line)
        print ip                

    def filterIPFromLine(self,line):
        ip = None
        if '/var/ossec/active-response/bin/firewall-drop.sh' in  str( line ).lower():
            ip = re.match( "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" )

            try:
                socket.inet_aton(ip[0])
                ip = ip[0]
            except socket.error:
                pass
        return ip


tom = PyWatch('example.log')
tom.start()
```

The code is running, it returns no errors, but for some reason it never reaches the `run()` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the line:

```
            yield line
```

This is causing `run()` not to, well... run! It's not obvious why it's there in the first place.

According to the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org), [the `yield` expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) is only used when defining a generator function, and **when a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a generator**. That generator then controls the execution of a generator function. **The execution starts when one of the generator's methods is called.**

Since you're not calling any generator methods (such as `next()`), then the function doesn't execute.

Here is a quick demonstration:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def fun():
...     print 'Starting'
...     for i in range(10):
...             yield i
... 
>>> fun()
<generator object fun at 0x10678c460>
>>> _.next()
Starting
0
>>>
```

There is [an excellent explanation of the yield expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/78845) as an answer to [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) .

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the problem:

When I run your code, I get:

```
initiating...
running...
```

Which indicates that the run() method does execute correctly.

Did you correctly import the threading module on top of your code ?

```
import threading
```

Comment: Updated the code, this is my full code, if I delete a few methods it does indeed run. I don't get it what adding methods would change :/

Comment: @LucasKauffman: It's not adding *methods* that changed your output, but what you have added to **`run()`**. See my answer.